# Why numpy shows overflow warning when calculating sigmoid function over a vector

Tags: python, numpy, overflow, sigmoid

I define sigmoid function as

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return np.array(1,dtype=np.float32)/(np.array(1,dtype=np.float32)+np.e**(-x))
```

From certain process, I obtain a vector V

```
array([-17.16755  , -43.38096  , -50.662907 ,  -4.6828723,  30.241184 ,
    33.176258 ,  -2.6549878,  39.39479  ,  30.862703 ,  43.635265 ,
    -1.6571381, -32.128    ,  29.632397 ,  49.887814 , -51.056076 ,
   -21.155422 , -15.083642 ,  -8.165374 , -30.164135 , -44.869812 ,
   -41.42827  , -51.831993 , -30.47157  ,  63.4149   , -36.810406 ,
   -91.20894  ,  34.144974 ,  25.610632 ,  31.795725 ,  30.754189 ,
    25.77716  , -36.224567 , -20.628532 ,  17.782776 , -47.377155 ,
    27.018559 , -35.27353  , -67.69212  ,  42.793926 ,  17.365631 ,
   -50.17401  ,  13.575214 , -25.257996 ,  29.324886 ,  41.678135 ,
    22.198011 , -27.206142 ,  53.277668 , -35.56072  , -40.728275 ,
   -65.53719  ,  37.86692  , -55.85548  , -41.653015 , -31.345434 ,
    28.519646 ,   3.410955 , -37.82836  , -21.12491  ,  14.327229 ,
    41.04181  ,  -5.9667635, -36.600582 , -18.411482 , -17.701595 ,
   -56.644577 , -30.59841  ,  39.21502  ,  32.131046 ,  37.98612  ,
   -38.354282 ,  53.85536  , -14.2249365, -49.56412  , -43.871513 ,
   -45.763306 , -37.88479  , -56.158215 , -46.685528 , -54.468544 ,
    43.334534 , -33.170887 , -33.829945 ,  25.237522 , -18.438    ,
   -15.322146 ,  41.810265 , -11.0000925,  37.11111  ,  22.03616  ,
   -59.27206  ,  15.850861 , -27.838043 , -37.638874 ,  36.973534 ,
    36.29362  , -41.293266 ,  34.956223 ,  19.00378  ,  -2.5246155,
    61.8252   ,  -8.748521 , -35.123108 ,  42.100964 , -21.26229  ,
   -49.73235  , -24.923735 ,  46.17717  , -11.523466 ,  53.184673 ,
   -47.184753 , -35.34979  , -34.720116 ,  39.09728  ,  39.863754 ,
    15.549853 , -13.079846 ,  45.43235  , -27.67498  , -48.726383 ,
    33.66749  ,  42.371788 ,  29.571087 , -27.311522 , -38.875412 ,
   -60.134632 , -51.25539  ,  26.069319 ], dtype=float32)
```

The following runs normally:

```
for i in V:
    sigmoid(i)
```

**But `sigmoid(V)` returns `FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in power`**

I found that the problem is produced by `V[25]=-91.20894`, which is the lowest number of the array and therefore the biggest result for `np.e**-V`.

I find specially ackward that `sigmoid(V[25])` will return a valid result `2.4460271112816884e-40`, but `sigmoid(V[25:26])` returns `overflow` again.

I would like to know if there is a way to perform this operation quickly.

I could solve the problem by defining my arrays as np.float64 (which actually works) or by multiplying the elements of the dot product one by one, but I'm performing millions of operations and my code require several minutes to run, so I would appreciate any solution or guide to avoid increasing computational time.

Comment: its working fine, might be some version changes, did you check that

Comment: @Nagakiran I just realised that, if I build an array coping the numbers above the function works, but it still doesn't work with the real vector I have. I wouldn't know how to paste the vector itself...

Comment: please try checking shape of your vector and type of your vector, those might be mismatches at here

Comment: @Nagakiran I am certain that shapes match, is a 64 vector with dtype np.float32

Comment: @Nagakiran Additionally, if I run sigmoid(V.astype(np.float64)), the function works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are using the python operator of power, which might be causing the issue. Numpy uses broadcasting, so the implementation is much simpler. Try replacing all your arrays of 1s with just 1.

So it would be `1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))`.

Comment: I just tried, but it still doesn't works. Also, I used np.array(1,dtype=np.float32) because I was told that this would work faster, as it is better to tell numpy the type of number I want it to use (As I'm building a NN, even little improvements are very important). Am I wrong?

Comment: If that is the case, you should use `np.ones()`. I am not sure why it isn't working then. I have done multiple courses where this implementation works. Could you check your python and numpy version maybe?